Using COUNT in a SQL Query but not getting accurate results
I've tried many solutions and different WHERE clauses. I'm getting a COUNT of 20 rows, but accurately there are 23 matching rows.
Here is my query:
DECLARE @CaseNum as NVARCHAR(12) = '19382006'

DECLARE @Enc as INTEGER = '717997'

DECLARE @START_Enc INTEGER 

SET @START_Enc = (
    SELECT MIN(Encounter_code)
    FROM tblVisitLog
    WHERE CaseNumber = @CaseNum
    AND Discipline = 'PT'
    AND VisitType <> 'M'
)

SET @Enc = (
    SELECT Encounter_code
    FROM tblVisitLog
    WHERE Encounter_code = @Enc
    AND Discipline = 'PT'
    AND VisitType <> 'M'
)

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT V.Encounter_code) 
FROM tblVisitLog V
INNER JOIN tblScheduleData S
    ON S.Encounter_code = V.Encounter_code
WHERE V.Encounter_code  BETWEEN @START_Enc AND @Enc
AND V.CaseNumber = @CaseNum
AND V.Discipline = 'PT'
AND S.ItemType <> 'M'
AND S.Item_Status IN('V', 'C')
AND S.Item_Status NOT IN ('A', 'D', 'I', 'CA','CE','CC','CN','CS','CP','CD')

The answer is +3, +2, or +1 of the COUNT, there doesn't seem to be a number that I can accurately just add to the COUNT.
Here are the fields I'm using:



Encounter_code
CaseNumber
Discipline
Item_Status
ItemType




716946
19382006
PT
V
E


717967
19382006
PT
V
T


717969
19382006
PT
V
T


717970
19382006
PT
V
T


717971
19382006
PT
V
T


717973
19382006
PT
V
T


717974
19382006
PT
C
T


717977
19382006
PT
V
T


717978
19382006
PT
V
T


717979
19382006
PT
V
T


717980
19382006
PT
V
T


717982
19382006
PT
V
T


717983
19382006
PT
V
T


717985
19382006
PT
V
T


717986
19382006
PT
V
T


717988
19382006
PT
V
T


717991
19382006
PT
V
T


717992
19382006
PT
C
T


717995
19382006
PT
V
T


717997
19382006
PT
V
T



Obviously, I'm doing something wrong. Please help! Thank you,

Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results. Ideally provide the sample data as DDL+DML so we can just copy it an run it.

Building it now, 15 Minutes

You mention 23 matching ROWS but then perform COUNT(DISTINCT V.Encounter_Code).  Are you sure the 23 matching rows have 23 unique v.encounter_code values? Wy not use count(*)?

I see that you are setting @Enc twice. The second assignment uses a query that looks like can only yield the existing @Enc value. Aside from that, the general technique for debugging unexpected COUNT() values is to modify the select list to just return the data being counted, including the primary keys or other uniquely  identifying information from the source tables. That should give you the evidence needed to diagnose your problem.

I have tried the query with COUNT(*), but the number is not accurate either. I'm trying to eliminate dupes by using the DISTINCT keyword.

T N I'm only COUNTING DISTINCT Encounter_Codes, I can try removing the 2nd definition of @Enc to see if that resolves the issue. Just tried, same incorrect result.

Also, the S.Item_Status IN ('V', 'C') condition makes the following S.Item_Status NOT IN (...) condition unnecessary.  Did you only intended one or the other perhaps?

T N - Just another of my many attempts to get the right results, the NOT IN isn't needed.

@JackW9653 - You should add your data to your original question. If unfamiliar with markdown formatting, paste what you have for data. Someone can help with formatting. Be sure to post matching data from both source tables. You prior (now deleted) comment appeared to only have tblScheduleData . Table schema (column definitions) may also be needed. Lastly, update your expected results to match your posted sample data (which only had 5 rows).

T N- thank you, the tables had 42 rows, too many for posting here.

@JackW9653 - You've posted tblScheduleData, but have not yet posted corresponding tblVisitLog data.  Given what you have so far, I generated some dummy tblVisitLog and added it to this db<>fiddle. As is, both tables have 20 rows and the query results show a count = 20. Perhaps you can replace the tblVisitLog data in that fiddle with your live data and post the updated fiddle URL back here.

I moved this question to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78846179/count-function-not-returning-accurate-results.
I tried to post the fields I was using, but they did not show correctly, sorry

If you provide a [mre] using DBFiddle you'll have an answer much faster than all these comments to explain.

try simplifying the query removing the INNER JOIN and using a subquery in my example.
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT V.Encounter_code) 
FROM tblVisitLog V
WHERE V.Encounter_code  BETWEEN @START_Enc AND @Enc
AND V.CaseNumber = @CaseNum
AND V.Discipline = 'PT'
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tblScheduleData S
    WHERE S.Encounter_code = V.Encounter_code
    AND S.ItemType <> 'M'
    AND S.Item_Status IN('V', 'C')
    AND S.Item_Status NOT IN ('A', 'D', 'I', 'CA','CE','CC','CN','CS','CP','CD')
);

this may help to eliminate the issue with the join.
also, you can duplicate by using the following query.
SELECT COUNT(*), Encounter_code
FROM tblVisitLog
GROUP BY Encounter_code
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

SELECT COUNT(*), Encounter_code
FROM tblScheduleData
GROUP BY Encounter_code
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

this will help you to check is there are any duplicate rows in either table.

Vijay - Your solution is much more elegant, but I'm still getting inaccurate COUNTs. There were duplicates, but they were from years ago and they will not factor in the current results.
